# Limit of a sequence $x_n$ where $x_{n+1}=1-(n+1)x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Consider the recursive relation
>
> $x_{n+1} = 1 - (n+1) x_n, \quad \quad x_0 = 1 - \frac{1}{e}$.
>
> (a) Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$

I have tried this problem by writing down the Maclaurin series of $x_0$ but it getting more complicated after $x_3$. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax instead of a photo so that future users can more easily find your question by searching.

Comment: Compute a few values of the sequence, but don't sum the integers, and take $n!$ as an overall common factor. What you get is $n!$ multiplied by a subtraction of $e^{-1}$ and the $n$-th truncation of the series $e^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$. Then use Taylor with remainder in Lagrange form.

Comment: If you divide $x_{n+1}=1-(n+1)x_n$ by $(n+1)!$ you get $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{x_n}{n!}$$set $y_{n}=\frac{x_n}{n!}$, then $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-y_n$

Answer (score 3):

You noticed the importance of Maclaurin in this problem, it is already a good point.

Let $y_n:= \frac{x_n}{n!}(-1)^n$, then $y_0=1-e^{-1}$ and
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(-1)^{n+1}+y_n$$

So by induction
$$y_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} -e^{-1}$$
By now, you can observe that the first term- the sum- is an approximation of $e^{-1}$ by using Maclaurin's expansion of $e^{x}$ at $x=0$, and $y_n$ is the residu of that approximation.

The rest of this solution will rely on the study of the speed of the convergence of such residues. And I leave you that final touch of Midas.